# Total Cable/Splitter loss calculation for Gain value compensation

Tags: antenna-array, power-divider

If there is an 8 port splitter attached to cables feeding an array, is the total Cable/Splitter loss = S21 measurement for each port (with terminations on others) OR I have to add the S21 value of each port?

This is confusing me. 
So I expect -9dB for an 8-way. 
I get -10.5 in my S21 measurements. (For each port, with slight variations from one port to the other)

So is the total loss for all 8 ports feeding array is the difference between 10.5 and 9dB (i.e. 1.5 dB to be added to Gain) or I'm completely wrong?

Another Q: If I only use 2 ports of the 8 way splitter... does the expected value become -3dB? Or it always remains -9dB regardless of port terminations?

Your explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -9 dB figure is only in the ideal case - if the network is lossless. However, in practice, there will always be losses - how much depends on the quality of the device as well as the frequency.

In addition, you need to ensure that your test setup is calibrated. These kinds of measurements should be done using a VNA and phase stable cables, propper torque on the connectors, and calibrate it before measuring at the frequency and power you desire to use using a STOL-calibration. You could easily lose 1.5 dB just in cables and connectors if they are not calibrated out.

To answer your second question: No, you will still get at least 9 dB loss. The splitter cannot tell what load is connected - and if you use only 2 ports and terminate the others with Zo, it will still put the same signal power into the load. Of course, nothing stops you from using a 4-to-1 combiner to combine 4 ports back to one, but you will find additional losses, and there is the matter that you are better of just using a 2 way splitter in the first place.

What happens when the other ports are not terminated? Who knows! This depends on the topology.

Comment: Thanks, I have the VNA calibrated. I read -10.5dB. So I'm assuming that the added Gain to compensate for losses would be (-10.5dB minus -9dB). So that's an added 1.5dB Gain. Is this correct for whether I use 2 ports or 8? I don't need to add all port values?

Comment: What do you mean by added gain? If you want to know input power to get certain output power on each port, just add 10.5 dB.

Comment: If the array has a Gain of 6dB without accounting for splitter and cable loss. If I add the loss compensation for the 8 antennas fed by 8-way splitter.... I just add 10.5dB?

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes, you should just subtract the 1.5 dB. 
Of course, when we talk about antenna gain, we don't actually mean it radiates more power - that would violate the conservation of energy. The gain means that it will radiate more directional.

Comment: So it's an added 1.5 dB Gain not the whole 10.5 dB? (Thanks for being patient Joren).